# Is there a limit on Raspberry PI's display size?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, display, pitft, crash

I have been using Raspberry PI 2 and 3 for the last year and a half with no problem. However, over time I have noticed that different sizes of display connected to the PI effected how my software ran. For instance, with the 7inch, 3.5 pitft and 2.8 pitft displays my software doesn't have any issues running, but any displays bigger than 7 inch seems to crash my software. My software suppose to run 24/7. It doesn't make any sense whatsoever. Display itself doesn't show any sign of issues like say 19 inches or 24 inches. So, Is there a display size limit for Raspberry PI?

Comment: the physical size is irrelevant .... display resolution and display drivers are the determining factors

Comment: Does your software use the screen height/width to do any calculations or for display purposes?

Comment: @CoderMike Yes, it does.

Comment: I would suggest that there is a problem with your code relating to larger screen sizes?